# Adjusting Time Averages to Show Weekdays or Weekends

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, dayofweek

I am tracking the date/time when I say goodnight to Alexa. The entries are super weird and unhelpful strings, not dates and times:

Sample data:

```
January 25, 2021 at 12:03AM
January 25, 2021 at 11:27PM
January 26, 2021 at 11:17PM
```

Alexa just dumps these unconventional date/time strings into A1-A??? on the first tab.

I am using this formula to show my average bedtime each month:

```
= QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(
            IF(LEN(A2:A), {
                MONTH(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\D+") & 1),
                REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\D+"),
                IF(TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+:\d+.*")) > 0.5,
                    TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+:\d+.*")),
                    TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+:\d+.*")) + 1)
            }, "")),
        "Select Col1,Col2 ,avg(Col3) where Col1 is not null 
        group by Col1, Col2 Order By Col1 asc label Col1 '#', Col2 'Month', avg(Col3)
        'Average bedtime'
        ")
```

But really, I don’t care so much about weekends as I do about weeknights. Stumped on how to adjust the formula so that it only shows Sun-Thu nights.

To make it trickier.. if I went to bed after midnight on a Thursday (*gasp*), that should still be included.

Turning to those who have madder skills than me!

Thanks for your help,

Drew

Comment: There's more to it than accounting for Thursday bedtimes after midnight. You'd have to account for ruling OUT Saturday bedtimes after midnight; how bedtimes before or after midnight and on which days affect which month a bedtime fell in (e.g., January 1 at 12:03AM is really a December bedtime, and the formula then needs to figure out if December 31 was a Sunday-Thursday); distinguishing January 2021 from January 2022 times, and more.

Comment: This can all be done, of course. But keep in mind that this is a free forum attended by volunteers during their free time. You'll increase your chance of receiving help if you start by sharing a link to a spreadsheet that contains sufficient (20+) data.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should take into account the edge cases mentioned above:

*cell B2:*

```
=arrayformula( 
  regexreplace(A2:A, "^([\w, ]+) at ([\w: ]+)$", "$1 $2") 
)
```

*cell C2:*

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      text(B2:B - (B2:B - int(B2:B) < timevalue("4:00 AM")), "mmmm"),       
      text(B2:B - (B2:B - int(B2:B) < timevalue("4:00 AM")), "ddd"), 
      timevalue(B2:B) + (B2:B - int(B2:B) < timevalue("4:00 AM")) 
    }, 
    "select Col1, avg(Col3) 
     where Col2 matches 'Sun|Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu' 
     group by Col1 
     pivot Col2", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

Format the result cells as **Format > Number > Time**.

Comment: Hi Doubleunary, the Cell C2 formula gave me an error; Ed's solution below did the trick but if you have any adjustments for yours I'm curious to see it in action... the approach is really interesting!

Comment: Hmm... the formulas seem to work fine with the sample data you show above pasted into cells A2:A4. Please share a [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial solution.

```
=ArrayFormula(query(if(A2:A = "",, {
  month(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.*) at")),
  REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\D+"),
  REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\d+:.*") + (REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "\D\D$")="AM"),
  mod(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "(.*) at") + REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A, "at (.*)")-1, 7)
 }),
        "Select Col1,Col2 ,avg(Col3) where Col4 > 0.5 and Col4 < 5.5 
        group by Col1, Col2 Order By Col1 asc label Col1 '#', Col2 'Month', avg(Col3)
        'Average bedtime'
        "))
```

It does not address the year and end of month issues raised by Erik. Any before noon entries on the first of a month should be included in the previous month.
Col4 at 0.5 would be Sunday noon and 5.5 would be Friday noon. Ed

Comment: Thanks for your solution, Ed - this does seem to work, it's hard to proof but I see the times I earlier now that my later weekends are removed.